# PHP CodeSniffer vs Mess Detector

Tags: php, code-analysis, code-beautification, lint, phpstorm

I'm working on cleaning up my code and came across some PHP linters: [Mess Detector](http://phpmd.org/about.html) [Code Sniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/) through PHPStorm's inspection settings.

Should I use these together or just one?

What benefits does each provide?

What are the differences?

Requirements: free, integrates with PHPStorm

Note: If this is not the right place for this question, my apologies. I looked for a few minutes at the different options and this seemed the best fit. If it is not, where should I post this? And can someone move it?

Comment: To make this question on-topic here, you should list your requirements (i.e. which features do you need?), and answers might recommend Mess Detector, Code Sniffer or something else.

Comment: I don't even know what reqs I need. Isn't it a given that I need some kind of linter based on the question? Though I only want one of these two as nothing else works with PHPStorm.

Comment: If this isn't on topic here, where else can I post this question?

Comment: I don’t know much about linters, so I have no idea which features/restrictions they might have. But in case there is not much, your question could simply be like "I need a linter that integrates with PhpStorm.", I guess. However, you might be able to give further restrictions, maybe like: price, up-to-dateness, supported versions, what should the linter absolutely not do, workflow, ….